# Error en expresión regular: "Range out of order in character class"

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy usando una expresión regular para evitar que se escriban caracteres diferentes a letras en un textarea:

```
/[A-Za-Z]/ig
```

pero me lanza este error relacionado a la expresión regular:

> Range out of order in character class

¿Por qué sucede esto?

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", checker);


function checker() {
  var textArea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
  for (let element of textArea) {
    element.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
      var letra = "which" in event ? event.which : event.keyCode,
        patron = /[A-Za-Z]/ig;
      if (!patron.test(letra)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Además del error en `a-Z` que te comentaron (porque el rango está mal, `a` está después de la `Z`), tené en cuenta que el evento keypress no se va a disparar cuando no se presione una tecla (como con cualquier celular por ejemplo)

Comment: Y en ese caso qué se debe hacer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error "***Range out of order in character class***" significa que, dentro de la [clase de caracteres](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-character-set), hay un rango al revés. En una clase de caracteres se puede utilizar cualquier rango, por ejemplo `[!-z]`, `[#-@]` o el que quieras, siempre y cuando el primero tenga un [valor de caracter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin) menor al segundo.
<sub>-Normalmente hablamos de [código ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Caracteres_imprimibles_ASCII) porque el bloque latino básico es el que más usamos, pero también vale para cualquier valor de [punto de código](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Repertorio_de_caracteres) en Unicode, no sólo los más comunes entre 0 y 127.</sub>

> [image: Tabla ASCII]

Hay 3 motivos por los que se puede generar el error:

1. Se quería incluir un `-`, pero no se escapó.
   <sup>Ejemplo: cuando se quiere coincidir con uno de estos símbolos `[,-!"#]`, el guión tiene que estar escapado para no generar un rango, como `[,\-!"#]` (o estar al inicio o al final de la clase, donde nunca es un rango).</sup>
2. Se están usando corchetes, pero no se quiere tener una clase de caracteres.
   <sup>Ejemplo: para coincidir con el texto `"[ax - b]"`, se debe escapar el corchete inicial para que no genere una clase, como `\[ax - b]`.</sup>
3. Exclusivamente un rango al revés, comúnmente por un error al usar mayúsculas, como en el caso de `[a-Z]`.

En tu caso, `a-Z` es incorrecto, porque la `a` tiene el valor 97 y la `Z` el valor 90 (está al revés). En cambio, podría ser `[Z-a]`, que incluye a los caracteres `Z`, `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`, `` ` `` y `a`.
<sub>-*Ya sé, seguramente fue sólo un error tipográfico pero quería explicarlo.*</sub>

El regex que coincide con una letra de la a a la z en mayúsculas o minúsculas es `/^[A-Za-z]$/`.
O, lo que es lo mismo (si usamos el modificador `/i` para ignorar mayúsculas/minúsculas):
`/^[a-z]$/i`

Pero no nos olvidemos de la ñ y las vocales con tilde del español:

```
/^[a-záéíóúüñ]$/i
```

---

> Nota aparte: **Validar en el evento keypress es cosa del pasado**.
>   No se recomienda, ya no se usa, por dos motivos principales:
>
> 1. Actualmente, muchos ingresos de texto no son con teclas. Los celulares no tienen teclas, o cuando copiás y pegás texto tampoco
>      estás enviando una tecla... y ninguno de estos dispara un evento
>      keypress.
>      <sub>-Hacé la prueba, abrí esta página en tu celular y vas a ver que el código de tu pregunta no dispara al evento y, por eso, no muestra el error.</sub>
> 2. Y ya no se acostumbra prohibir el ingreso de nada. ¿Recordás alguna página *profesional* que impida que ingreses un caracter? Al
>      contrario, lo que se suele hacer es permitir todo, y marcar en algún
>      color o mostrar un pequeño mensaje cuando es incorrecto. Incluso,
>      por lo general no se marca *mientras* se está escribiendo, sino cuando
>      se pierde el foco o cuando se envía el formulario.
>
> Una alternativa sencilla (especialmente viendo que ya estás
>   definiendo el doctype como HTML5) es usar el atributo [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input#attr-pattern) de
>   los inputs. Implica cambiar el textarea por un input, pero como no
>   estás permitiendo espacios ni saltos de línea, parecería lógico... y
>   chau código!
>
> ```css
> input[type=text] {
>     width: 40ch;
> }
> input:invalid {
>     border: 2px solid red;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <form action="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQUj9m.jpg">
>   <input type="text"
>          placeholder="Ingrese el texto"
>          pattern="[a-záéíóúüñA-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]*"
>          title="Sólo letras de la 'a' a la 'z'"
>   >
>   <br>
>   <input type="submit"
>          value="Probar"
>   >
> </form>
> ```
>
> - Actualmente está soportado por la mayoría de los navegadores modernos (IE10+)
>     ([ver compatibilidad](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern)).
>
> Pero si te interesa ver cómo validar un textarea, te recomiendo
>   leer [*Validación de formulario de datos (MDN)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Validacion_formulario_datos).
>
> O, si realmente la idea es tener un control de cada uno de los
>   cambios, los eventos a tener en cuenta son: [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/submit), [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Reference/Events/blur) e
>   [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/input).

Comment: Buenísima tu información, gracias Mariano !

Comment: creo que no habia visto un snippet dentro de un `>` de cita

Answer (score 1):

El error del regex se debe a que incluiste el en los caracteres **A-Z** y **a-Z** y no existe el rango de caracteres **a-Z** sino **a-z**.

Igualmente como veo el código, debes utilizar event.key

Código modificado:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",checker);


function checker(){
 var textArea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
 for (let element of textArea) {
  element.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
  var letra = event.key,
      patron = /[A-Z]/ig;
  if(!patron.test(letra)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }  
  });
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por que al encerrarlo entre () el regex funcionaria ?

Comment: No es necesario encerrarlo en paréntesis, ya hice la corrección

Comment: El único error era el a-Z

Comment: El modificador `/g` es innecesario en este caso... Estaría bueno que expliques por qué `a-Z` está mal, fue la pregunta principal que hizo

Comment: Respuesta modificada y explica el porque el regex esta mal.... a-Z es un rango de caracteres inválida. o es A-Z o a-z, en tu caso como le pudiste el modificador i (ignore case) no es necesario poner los dos rangos.