# Cómo utilizar el atributo pattern de HTML5 en un input type = text

Tags: html5, regex

Tengo un formulario en el que entre otras cosas tengo que meter un email, pero tiene un patrón especial:

Ejemplos:

```
antonio001@ikasle.ehu.eus
alberto001@ikasle.ehu.es
```

Como podeis ver tiene que

- empezar con letras y
- luego seguido de esos 3 números
- despues del `@` tiene que tener seguido `ikasle.ehu`
- en el TLD tienes dos opciones, poner `eus` o poner `es`.

¿Cómo sería el patrón para lograr esto?

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo al menos? ¿Tienes una expresión regular desde la que partir?

Comment: Ya esta solucionado muchas gracias a todos

Comment: No creo que haya sido como para ponerla en espera. Hay 500 preguntas similares en StackOverflow (inglés) y allá que son fariseos en extremo no son tan quisquillosos con las preguntas de regex.

Comment: @amenadiel yo no la puse en espera, pero claramente OP no probo nada antes de venir a preguntar. y esta comunidad no es la misma, tenemos otras reglas y funcionamos de otra forma.

Comment: Sé que esta comunidad es otra y sé cómo funcionábamos. Parece que las cosas han cambiado mucho desde que me ausenté en marzo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La expresión regular sería

```
/^\w+\d{3}@ikasle\.ehu\.(eus|es)$/
```

Eso significa "comienza por al menos un carácter de texto o número  seguido de exactamente 3 números, luego un arroba, luego literalmente `ihasle.ehu.` terminado en `eus` o `es`.

```js
var regex=/^\w+\d{3}@ikasle\.ehu\.(eus|es)$/,
    correos = [
    "juanito00A@ikasle.ehu.es",
    "juanito001@ikasle.ehu.es",
    "juanita002@ikasle.ehu.eus",
    "juanito001@ikasle.ehu.com",
    "juanito001@ikasle.gmail.es",
    "005juanita001@ikasle.ehu.es"
    ];
    
correos.forEach(function(correo) {
  console.log(correo, regex.test(correo));
});
```

Ojo que según la especificación un correo válido puede contener muchos otros caracteres que sólo letras y números. (Sólo no te pongas creativo [ni leas los RFC](http://girders.org/blog/2013/01/31/dont-rfc-validate-email-addresses/). Aplica sentido común)

Para usar esa expresión en el atributo pattern tendrías que sacarle la envoltura en slashes.

Comment: Además, no es necesario `^` ni `$`, ya que el atributo `pattern` busca la coincidencia con todo el texto (es decir que están implícitos). Y ojo que `\w` incluye números, que quizás el autor no quiera en la primera parte... En vez del ejemplo en que usaste, quizás estaría bueno verlo usando un input con pattern (podés seguir como ejemplo [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/113165/127))

Comment: Efectívamente el último elemento de mi array incluye tu caso de borde. Completamente válido como correo. No tenía idea que el pattern incluía ^ y $. Es bueno saberlo. ;)